# In django prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)} doesn't show all words

Tags: python, django

I am using

```
prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

in my django admin area and when I type certain words like

```
 this is the first slug
```

into the title field

only

```
first-slug
```

is outputted in the slug field, and if I delete the "t"in the title field

the slug field will then output

```
his-first-slug
```

"is" and "the" won't show up

in the slug field. Why is that? or better yet How can I fix this so that anything I type in the title field is properly displayed in the slug field

Comment: I found out formerly that Django's javascript code for prepulating fields does not work properly. Once you have written a tittle and want to change that (+ automatically alter a slug field), you have to delete the value in the slug field, change title and after "save" it should autocomplete new and correct slug value. Or #2 option is to change slug manually ...That works for me (both #1 & #2)

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a filter in action that prevents certain words from ending up in the slug or url. You can see the source of that [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/urlify.js). What it does is that it makes sure that you don't end up with words or symbols in the slug/url that just shouldn't be there.

How to fix it? Just change the mentioned file in `/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/urlify.py` and you should be good to go.